# Huge file as the data source for mincemeat.py

Tags: python, mapreduce, mincemeat

I am planning to use mincemeat.py for my map reduce task on a ~100GB file. After seeing the example code from mincemeat, it seems I need to input an in-memory dictionary as the data source. So, what is the right way to provide my huge file as the data source for mincemeat?

Link to mincemeat: https://github.com/michaelfairley/mincemeatpy

Comment: Tried iterator instead?

Comment: Seems I have to create a complete dictionary, beforehand. Do you want me to try iterator for file? but, I need to add the file contents to dict. This is where I am a bit confused.

Comment: Citing from github page: datasource: ...You may use a dict, or any other data structure which
implements the iterator protocol (__iter__() and next()) for returning all keys...  Seems it is the only reasonable way to go with huge files, though I'd like to know exact practical solution as well as you :)

Comment: Just don't forget to fix your solution when you find one, friend

Comment: @dmitry, Yes, surely I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example and the concept I would have thought that you would ideally:

1. Produce an iterator for the data source,
2. Spilt the file into a number of meerly large files on a number of servers and then
3. Merge the results.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, let me check in this direction.